# Firefox Developer Edition get all event listeners registered on an element getEventListeners

Tags: javascript, firefox, developer-tools

I want to get all the event listeners registered on an element, in JavaScript in the developer tools console.

In Chrome, `getEventListeners(domElement)` exists.

In Firebug, that apparently exists too. Firebug is discontinued. I found [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/) which says:

> So it’s sad that Firebug is now reaching end-of-life in the Firefox browser, with the release of Firefox Quantum (version 57) next month. **The good news is that all the capabilities of Firebug are now present in current Firefox Developer Tools.**

Emphasis mine.

However, `getEventListeners` is not working in my installation of Firefox Developer Edition  78.0b3.

So how do I get a list of event listeners registered on an element in the console?

Comment: Do you want to do this *in code* in the browser console or something? Or just see them in devtools?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I might have to make a new question, I realise this is A/B. I want to call those event listeners dynamically. I can't just inspect element > events and call those functions, because they are not globally defined.

Answer (score 3):

According to this page: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1164285 this is being worked on, so `getEventListeners` is not implemented yet in the new Firefox.

It's possible though to find the element in the `Inspector` panel, and to the right of it there is an `event` button, which shows event listeners. You can inspect them and find their location in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I can't figure out how to call the event listeners from the console though

Comment: Maybe you could monkey patch event listeners? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417142/how-can-i-watch-event-handlers-being-added-to-an-element
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EgGgAOhegkgJ:https://www.mikedoesweb.com/2018/monkey-patching-event-listeners/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Maybe you could also use `jQuery._data( element, "events" );` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Comment: I believe the jQuery option only works if the events have been registered with jQuery? For the monkey patching, it would work, but I have to make sure that addEventListener is overridden before the web page calls it. Do you know how to monkey patch it from the console "before" the page loads?

Comment: Not sure if you can pause the web site in the console before it loads, but you could use Tampermonkey or a Chrome Extension with `run_at` `document_start` to monkey patch it, or (but not sure exactly) you could pause the web site using `debugger API`, and `Fetch` method in a Chrome extension: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/ and then use the console to monkey patch listeners, but if you use a Chrome Extension, then the first method should be easier

Comment: The monkey patch doesn't seem to capture `on` assignments?

Comment: Yes, on-event assignments should also be monkey patched. I will post it here for future readers: 
`const originalSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onclick').set;
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onclick', {
set: function (val) {
console.log('onclick called', val);
return originalSetter.call(this, val); 
}
});`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238373/re-bind-onclick-on-event-listeners-for-debugging

Comment: Also it might not capture event listeners declared inside HTML: `<element onclick="console.log('clicked')">`