# Re-bind onclick, on* event listeners for debugging

Tags: javascript, dom-events, getter-setter, setter

I want to monkeypatch event listener registrations.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417182/3310334) showing how to do it for `addEventListener`:

> ```
> const nativeEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
> EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(...args) {
>   if (this.matches('div') && args[0] === 'click') {
>     console.log('listener is being added to a div');
>     debugger;
>   }
>   nativeEventListener.apply(this, args);
> }
>
> // then, when an event listener is added, you'll be able to intercept the call and debug it:
> document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
>   console.log('clicked');
> });
> ```

But this won't cover `onclick`, `onkeydown`, etc. assignments.

I don't know how to do the same for those, because

```
const nativeOnClick = HTMLElement.prototype.onclick;
```

Throws a TypeError

> ```
> TypeError: 'get onclick' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.
> ```

Now I wonder if there is a special way to retrieve *specifically*  the setter and getter for `onclick` etc. individually, but I've had no luck so far with my google searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the original setter function with:

```
const originalSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onchange').set;
```

If you want to redefine a property, you should look at using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).